# Need help understanding rstrip() method

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I've been messing around with pulling `'\n'` off lists, and it makes me curious what is actually happening under the hood.

Why, for example, does the code below not change the values of my list?

```
numList = ['13\n', '14\n', '15\n']

for x in numList:
    x = x.rstrip('\n')
```

When I do it in the shell it prints out the stripped values, but doesn't update numList.  But for some reason the code below does change the values of my list:

```
numList = [x.rstrip() for x in numList]
```

Something like the below doesn't seem to have any effect at all:

```
for x in numList:
    x.rstrip('\n')
```

So basically, when can you use the `for x in someList:` syntax, and when do you need something like the second example?

Answer (score 7):

The issue is not with `rstrip()` . When you iterate over a list using `for` loop, as -

```
for x in numList:
```

Here the name x is just the reference to the object inside the list, and when you do -

```
x = x.rstrip('\n')
```

You just change  `x` to point to a different string object/reference, you do not change the reference inside the list. If you want to change elements like this using `for` loop, you should `enumerate` over the list and then change the element at that index. Example -

```
for i, x in enumerate(numList):
    numList[i] = x.rstrip('\n')
```

Though in your case, this is not needed, as the list comprehension (you are doing) would be the best method to do what you want.

Also, when you do -

```
for x in numList:
    x.rstrip('\n')
```

It does not change `x` , because strings are immutable in python, `x.rstrip('\n')` actually returns a new string object with `'\n'` stripped from the right side.

Also, in the list comprehension -

```
numList = [x.rstrip() for x in numList]
```

You are creating a new list with the strings as `x.rstrip()` , and then you are making numList point to that new list, it did not change the old list , so if you do something like -

```
oldRef = newList
numList = [x.rstrip() for x in numList]
print(oldRef)
```

You would be able to see that oldRef is still the same , its just that numList now points to a new list.

Comment: Beautiful explanation